# Is it Mongo.Collection or Meteor.Collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In the source code in the example apps I've viewed including http://thejackalofjavascript.com/meteor-js-build-apps-lightning-fast/ and https://www.meteor.com/examples/wordplay the former used Meteor.Collection() and the latter used Mongo.Collection() to define their collections.  What is the difference between the two and what is the difference in use cases?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Meteor.Collection` was renamed `Mongo.Collection` in [0.9.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v091-2014-sep-04). The change is currently backward compatible, however you should switch to using `Mongo.Collection` for any new projects. It looks like the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) have mostly been updated except for the wording in the *Data and security* section.

Comment: Actually I just tried running a new project on my local host with Meteor .9.1.1 installed and collections named Mongo.Collection prevented the app from starting up. Maybe you have it the other way around?

Comment: I'm certain this is correct. It's always been `Meteor.Collection` and the change has been very recent. To demonstrate this, have a look at [this meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/HnhECZsMqFDWM9yDC). Running 0.9.1.1, it will work with either namespace. If you switch to an earlier version of meteor and use `Mongo.Collection`, it will fail. If it isn't working locally for you, you should check that your local application is running 0.9.1.1 by running `meteor update`.

Comment: You are right. I updated to 0.9.1 right before 0.9.1.1 came out and when I updated to 0.9.1.1 I did it in my $Path but not for already created projects. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I responded to soon. Here is the error I got:

Comment: Last login: Wed Sep 10 22:25:27 on ttys000
White-Macbook-2:~ mac$ cd mcoseo
White-Macbook-2:mcoseo mac$ meteor update
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
This project is already at Meteor 0.9.1.1, the latest release.
White-Macbook-2:mcoseo mac$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/mcoseo ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
W20140910-22:26:26.952(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20140910-22:26:27.140(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/mac/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.28.1f38sye++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173

Comment: There is more to it than that but it won't fit in this space.

Comment: Its hard to tell from that. Do the errors go away if you change the namespace back to Meteor? If so, I wonder if some modules rely on how the collection is declared.

Comment: The Mongo name space definitely does not work with 0.9.1 but I'm not sure it doesn't work with 0.9.1.1 because I think updating my 0.9.1 project to 0.9.1.1 breaks the project altogether.

Comment: Ok, you are right, upgrading to 0.9.1.1 breaks the app and 0.9.1.1 is compatible with the Mongo.Collection namespace.

Comment: Sorry about the broken app. :( I guess that's a separate issue.

Comment: Maybe add a link to the [release notes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#backwards-compatible-renames)

Answer (score 4):

As per change in Meteor 0.9.1: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#backwards-compatible-renames

Backwards compatible renames:

Symbol renames:

Meteor.Collection -> Mongo.Collection

Meteor.Collection.Cursor -> Mongo.Cursor

Meteor.Collection.ObjectID -> Mongo.ObjectID

Deps -> Tracker